# Protect SWF+PHP

Tags: security, flash

I have developed some Flash + PHP games, and the game logic is in the PHP files. Flash is only for animations and UI. Now I have a client interested in my games, but we have some sort of deal so that he can use the games for just 2 month, and after, if he doesn't pay a fee, the games will stop working.

I want to protect my games, so that he cannot use them forever. I was thinking that when the game starts, it sends a request to my server and if my server responds PASS=123456, then the game will work, otherwise show a message with "GAME DISABLED".

Another method would be to move a part of the PHP logic to my server, but this might cause the games to work slower than intended.

I also tried Kindisoft's secureSWF but their software alters the functionality of some games.

Does anybody have some other ideas of how to protect this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the logic is not on your server first you have to make sure the flash files are protected as best as possible and then you can do any kind of checking from the game to your server (as long as the flash file doesn't get cracked it doesn't matter what kind of check you do).

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/protect-your-flash-files-from-decompilers-by-using-encryption/

here is a nice article about swf protection but in the end swf is still open format so as long as the files are not on your server and the logic is in the php files, no matter what you do it can still be craked.

That being said the best way to control the games is to have the logic on your server.

Comment: The logic is still on the server, and I know that flash can still be cracked. But I want that when someone tries to crack my files he shouldn't be able to do it in 1minute. And the efforts to decompile should be larger than actually paying for the flash applicaiton.

Comment: well using the techniques you can find in that article i think you will cover that just fine

Comment: Do you really think a 2 year old article is usefull ?

Answer (score 3):

Use public key authentication - authenticate his php server. Make your server Certificate Authority, keep public time-valid keys on his server and their private counterparts on your CA server. Every time the flash game starts - authenticate his server with your CA.
This solution is not very complicated and you can use standard tools for doing so. Also - without *really* hacking the flash app, he won't be able to overcome this check. It's also eavesdrop-resistant.
Biggest possible problem would be him using your php API without your flash app.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is a bit of a skilled coder (or even enthousiast google user ) it won't be hard for him to bypass the initial password-test.

The only secure thing to do (imo) is host the php on a server you control yourself

Comment: He can do that by using some DNS redirection ?